# How to use compare.linkage in the R package RecordLinkage -- unexpected output

Tags: r

I am using the compare.linkage function in the R package RecordLinkage,
and getting a result I know is wrong, so I know I'm misunderstanding something.
I am using R 3.2.3 for x64 Windows. I am very familiar with Stata but not so much with R. I just cross-posted at r-help.

I can create record pairs from the blocking fields but all pairs are unknown status (NA). I cannot create matches or non-matches. I want a simple working example of how to link datasets using the RecordLinkage package. It seems that the manual and the R Journal Vol. 2/2 only show how to de-duplicate a single dataset using the compare.dedup function, not how to link two datasets together using the compare.linkage function. I can reproduce the examples in the R Journal article, so my R installation is fine.

The example dataset in the manual have 500 and 10000 observations on 7 variables, but 1 observation and 2 variables will be enough to show the problem.
My first comparison pattern loooks like this:

```
  id1  id2 fname_c1 bm is_match
1  17  343        1  1       NA
```

Instead, I want and expect a comparison pattern that looks like this:

```
  id1  id2 fname_c1 bm is_match
1  17  343        1  1       1
```

My blocking variable is fname_c1 for first component of first name. My matching variable is bm for birth month. My understanding is that row 1 in my example output is the first row where fname_c1 matched in the underlying datasets. I want and expect is_match to be 1 when the matching variable bm=1 in both linkage datasets, as in the example.

For more details, this is what I typed and the R output:

```
> library(RecordLinkage)
> data(RLdata500)
> data(RLdata10000)
> RLdata500[17, ]
    fname_c1 fname_c2 lname_c1 lname_c2   by bm bd
17 ALEXANDER     <NA>  MUELLER     <NA> 1974  9  9
> RLdata10000[343, ]
     fname_c1 fname_c2 lname_c1 lname_c2   by bm bd
343 ALEXANDER     <NA>  BAUMANN     <NA> 1957  9  7
> rpairs <- compare.linkage(RLdata500,RLdata10000,blockfld=c(1),     exclude=c(2:5,7))
> rpairs$pairs[c(1:2), ] # Why is_match=NA? (should be 1)
  id1  id2 fname_c1 bm is_match
1  17  343        1  1       NA
2  17 2385        1  0       NA
> rpairs <- epiWeights(rpairs) # (Weight calculation)
> summary(rpairs) # (0 matches in Linkage Dataset)

Linkage Data Set

500 records in data set 1 
10000 records in data set 2 
47890 record pairs 

0 matches
0 non-matches
47890 pairs with unknown status


Weight distribution:
[omitted here to save space]
```

References:

1. Manual for Package ‘RecordLinkage’
   (Available online in PDF at
   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf)
2. R Journal article Article "The RecordLinkage Package: Detecting Errors in Data" 
   (Available online in PDF at
   https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Sariyar+Borg.pdf)

I saw something in the manual and R journal article about identity argument for true match results, but I guess I only need that for reference ("gold standard") datasets. There is a non-missing value (bm=1) for my example in both underlying datasets, so that is not why the result is NA. What am I missing? How does one link two simple datasets using compare.linkage in R?

Anders Alexandersson

andersalex@gmail.com

Comment: Hello Anders.. I am having exactly the same problem, have you figured this out yet?

Comment: Yes, the problem is just unexpected output. The solution is to not expect "matches" because it has a special meaning and requires reference data. I did not have reference data and most people don't. Simply continue as discussed in the article on page 64. All you can get is "classification" unless you have reference data. You must have reference data to get "true [match] status".

Comment: Thanks, most helpful.... RecordLinkage doesn't seem to get a lot of answers on questions on Stack Overflow, it seems :-(

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and I have the possible solution for this answer This is due to `identity` parameter.

from the sample data, in Record Linkage package, I found that this vector `identity.RLdata500` carry information about the duplicate records of `RLdata500` out of 500 records 50 are duplicate records

```
length(unique(identity.RLdata500))
[1] 450
```

I found the similar column in my dataset and stored as a separate vector and passed the vector to the identity parameter

```
New_data_seq
118
118

New_data_seq <- R_New_data_zero$SEQ_NO 
abc <- compare.dedup (R_New_data_zero,identity = New_data_seq) 


    BICODE ALCODE IS_T OID conc
     I      A     1    99   IA1
     I      A     1    99   IA1
abc$pairs[1:1, ]

id1 id2 BICODE ALCODE IS_T OID conc is_match
 1   2   1        1    1    1    1       1
```