# compare.dedup function can't find near duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm new to R and I'm trying to catch near duplicates in a dataset (Restaurant dataset) using **compare.dedup** function in Record Linkage package. unfortunately, it can't find any near duplicates. I tried the same function on other benchmark datasets like RLdata10000 and RLdata500, however i got the same results, zero matched records.

However they are doing record linkage not deduplication i tried to use their [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065163/how-to-use-compare-linkage-in-the-r-package-recordlinkage-unexpected-output), but also didn't work.

I have another question. how to remove near duplicates from a dataset using R?

Any Help please to catch and remove near duplicates.

Here is the code:

```
fz=read.csv("fz.csv",header=TRUE)

fz$name <- as.factor(fz$name)
fz$addr<- as.factor(fz$addr)
fz$city<- as.factor(fz$city)
fz$phone<- as.factor(fz$phone)
fz$type<- as.factor(fz$type)
str(fz)


identity.fz=c(1:864)
ddf <-compare.dedup(fz, identity=identity.fz)
dfw<-epiWeights(ddf)
summary(ddf)



Deduplication Data Set
 
 864 records  372816 record pairs 
 
 0 matches 

 372816 non-matches
  
0 pairs with unknown status
```

```
dput(head(RLdata500))
structure(list(fname_c1 = structure(c(19L, 42L, 114L, 128L, 112L, 
77L), .Label = c("ALEXANDER", "ANDRE", "ANDREA", "ANDREAS", "ANGELA", 
"ANGELIKA", "ANJA", "ANKE", "ANNA", "ANTJE", "ASTRID", "BAERBEL", 
"BENJAMIN", "BERND", "BERNHARD", "BIRGIT", "BRIGITTE", "BRITTA", 
"CARSTEN", "CHRISTA", "CHRISTAH", "CHRISTIAN", "CHRISTINA", "CHRISTINE", 
"CLAUDIA", "DANIEL", "DENNIS", "DETLEF", "DIETER", "EDITH", "ELISABETH", 
"ELKE", "ERIKA", "ERNA", "ERNST", "FLORIAN", "FRANK", "FRIEDA", 
"FRIEDRICH", "GABRIELE", "GABRIHELE", "GERD", "GERDA", "GERHARD", 
"GERTRUD", "GISELA", "GISOELA", "GUDRUN", "GUENTHER", "HANNELORE", 
"HANS", "HARALD", "HARTMHUT", "HARTMUT", "HEIKE", "HEINRICH", 
"HEINZ", "HELGA", "HELMUT", "HERMANN", "HERTHA", "HILDEGARD", 
"HOLGER", "HORST", "ILSE", "INGE", "INGEBORG", "INGEU", "INGO", 
"INGRID", "IRMGARD", "JAN", "JENS", "JOERG", "JOHANNES", "JOHANNNES", 
"JUERGEN", "JULIA", "JUTTA", "KARIN", "KARINW", "KARL", "KATHRIN", 
"KLAUS", "KURT", "LARS", "MANFRED", "MANUELA", "MARCEL", "MARGARETE", 
"MARIA", "MARIANNE", "MARIANNFE", "MARION", "MARKUS", "MARTIN", 
"MARTINA", "MATTHIAS", "MICHAEL", "MONIKA", "MONIYKA", "NADINE", 
"NICOLE", "NORBERT", "OLIVER", "OTTO", "PETER", "PETERS", "PETEVR", 
"PETRA", "RAINER", "RALF", "RENATE", "ROBERT", "ROLBF", "ROLF", 
"RUDOLF", "RUTH", "SABAINE", "SABINE", "SANDRA", "SIEGFRIED", 
"SIGRID", "SILKE", "SILVIA", "SONJA", "SONJAD", "STEFAN", "STEFANIE", 
"SUSANNE", "SVEN", "THOMAS", "THORSKTEN", "THORSTEN", "ULRICH", 
"ULRIKE", "URSULA", "UTE", "UWE", "VOLKER", "WALTER", "WERNER", 
"WERNIER", "WILFRIED", "WILHELM", "WOLFGANG"), class = "factor"), 
    fname_c2 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("ALEXANDER", 
    "ANDREAS", "ANGELIKA", "ANNA", "BARBARA", "BIRGIT", "EDITH", 
    "ELFRIEDE", "ELKE", "FRANK", "FRIEDRICH", "GISELA", "GUDRUN", 
    "GUENTHER", "JENS", "JUERGEN", "KARIN", "KLAUS", "NICOLE", 
    "SABINE", "SILKE", "URSULA", "WALTRAUD"), class = "factor"), 
    lname_c1 = structure(c(61L, 2L, 31L, 106L, 50L, 23L), .Label = c("ALBRECHT", 
    "BAUER", "BAUERH", "BAUMANN", "BECK", "BECKER", "BECKRR", 
    "BERGER", "BERGKANN", "BERGMANN", "BOEHM", "BOEHMR", "BRANDT", 
    "BRAUN", "BUSCH", "DIETRICH", "DIETTRICH", "ENGEL", "ERNSR", 
    "ERNST", "FISCHER", "FRANK", "FRANKE", "FRIEDRICH", "FUCHS", 
    "GRAF", "GROSS", "GUENTHER", "HAAS", "HAHN", "HARTMANN", 
    "HERRMANN", "HOFFMANN", "HOFFMSNN", "HOFMANN", "HORN", "HUBER", 
    "JAEGER", "JUNG", "KAISER", "KELLER", "KLEIBN", "KLEIN", 
    "KOCH", "KOEHLER", "KOERTIG", "KRAEMER", "KRAJSE", "KRAUSE", 
    "KRUEGER", "KUEHN", "KUHN", "LANG", "LANGE", "LANGK", "LEHMANN", 
    "LUDWIG", "MAIER", "MARTIN", "MAYER", "MEIER", "MEYER", "MOELLER", 
    "MUELLDR", "MUELLEPR", "MUELLER", "MUELLRR", "MYER", "NEUMANN", 
    "OTTO", "PETERS", "POHL", "RICHTER", "ROTH", "SAUER", "SCHAEFER", 
    "SCHMIDT", "SCHMITT", "SCHMITZ", "SCHNEIDER", "SCHNNIDER", 
    "SCHREIBER", "SCHROEDER", "SCHUBERT", "SCHULTE", "SCHULZ", 
    "SCHULZE", "SCHUMACHER", "SCHUSTER", "SCHUTE", "SCHWARZ", 
    "SEIDEL", "SIMON", "SOMMER", "STEIN", "THOMAS", "VOGEL", 
    "VOGT", "WAGNER", "WEBER", "WEISS", "WERNER", "WINKLER", 
    "WINTER", "WOLF", "WOLFF", "ZIEGLER", "ZIMMERMANN"), class = "factor"), 
    lname_c2 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("ENGEL", 
    "FISCHER", "KLEIN", "KRUEGER", "SCHMIDT", "SCHMITT", "SCHULZ", 
    "SCHULZE"), class = "factor"), by = c(1949L, 1968L, 1930L, 
    1957L, 1966L, 1929L), bm = c(7L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 7L), bd = c(22L, 
    27L, 30L, 2L, 13L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: From the help page for the function, it looks like incomplete matching requires the use of a phonetic function or string comparison function.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Thanks for your help, actually I added the  string comparison function and other function parameters but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @Shawn, what do you mean by reproducible dataset? like this?                                                                                                 **str(fz)
data.frame:864 obs. of  6 variables:
$name : Factor w/ 776 levels "'103 west'","'20 mott'",
$addr : Factor w/ 772 levels "'1 main st.'"
$city : Factor w/ 49 levels "'bel air'","'beverly hills'"
$phone: Factor w/ 857 levels "'212/ 219-2777'",
$type : Factor w/ 84 levels "''","'american (new)'",                                                 $class: int  0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 ...**

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I tried to use dput function, however it gives too much output can't be copied here.

Comment: You can also use `dput(head(data))` or use the `dput` of a subset of the data.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand i updated the question using dput(head(data))

Answer (score 1):

I saved the head of your data as `df` and ran this code. First, I changed two rows to be identical:

```
#### Make Identical Rows ###
df[1,] <- df[2,]
df[4,] <- df[2,]
df
```

Which looks like this now, where three rows are now exact duplicates:

```
  fname_c1 fname_c2 lname_c1 lname_c2   by bm bd
1     GERD     <NA>    BAUER     <NA> 1968  7 27
2     GERD     <NA>    BAUER     <NA> 1968  7 27
3   ROBERT     <NA> HARTMANN     <NA> 1930  4 30
4     GERD     <NA>    BAUER     <NA> 1968  7 27
5     RALF     <NA>  KRUEGER     <NA> 1966  1 13
6  JUERGEN     <NA>   FRANKE     <NA> 1929  7  4
```

Then you can create a number of different flags, but I've given three examples here: one flag for exact duplicates, one flag for exact same names, and one flag for certain spellings of names like "ER" for the `frame_c1` variable only. I removed some variables that just read as NA.

```
#### Create Flag for Exact/Near Dupes ####
df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number(),
         identical = duplicated(.),
         same.name = duplicated(bm),
         near.name = str_detect(string = fname_c1,
                                pattern = "ER")) %>% 
  select(-fname_c2,
         -lname_c2) # these were NA
```

Which gives you this:

```
  fname_c1 lname_c1   by bm bd row identical same.name near.name
1     GERD    BAUER 1968  7 27   1     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
2     GERD    BAUER 1968  7 27   2      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE
3   ROBERT HARTMANN 1930  4 30   3     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
4     GERD    BAUER 1968  7 27   4      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE
5     RALF  KRUEGER 1966  1 13   5     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
6  JUERGEN   FRANKE 1929  7  4   6     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE
```

You can mix and match conditional filters like this however you feel.

Comment: I'll try your answer to see if it can solve my problem. Thanks a lot dear